# How can I open this defold engine?

Tags: defold

I installed this folder [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kdD6.png)from the official site but, I couldn't open defold engine.When I press the button, it orders me to decompress it and repeat and repeat.Please help me...
(P.S:Now I can open it..Thank you...)

Answer (score 3):

Did you download the correct version? There's a _MACOSX folder in there that looks suspicious. In any case, you should be able to double click Defold.exe. What if you right-click and open?

My recommendation would otherwise be that you download and try the new editor instead of the old Eclipse based editor that you have downloaded.

Win 32 version: http://www.defold.com/download/editor2/Defold-x86-win32.zip
Win 64 version: http://www.defold.com/download/editor2/Defold-x86_64-win32.zip